# How to auto link assets after `yarn install` in React Native 0.60

Tags: react-native, autolink

So I have my custom library `my-library`, with a `react-native.config.js` file.

```
module.exports = {
  dependency: {
    assets: ['Fonts'],    // This lib contains custom fonts.
  }
};
```

When I do `yarn install my-library` somewhere in a different project, I need to manually run `react-native link my-library` to have the fonts available in my app.

Is it possible to link it automatically on `yarn install`?

Answer (score 0):

Read this https://facebook.github.io/react-native/blog/2019/07/03/version-60#native-modules-are-now-autolinked

You don't need to run `react-native link` anymore in most scenario.